# Why my code does not taking "-" but taking "+"

Tags: sql-server

```sql
select left(name,(charindex('_',name)-1)) from sys.tables
go
```

After excecuting this I am getting error.

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But when we execute below code I am getting result

```sql
select left(name,(charindex('_',name)+1)) from sys.tables
go
```

Why does the query fail when including the `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this myself so, so many times.

In the case when the column `name` contains no underscore, `CHARINDEX('_', name)-1` will yield `-1`, which is an invalid length to pass to `LEFT()`.

Comment: execute bellow command you will get the position of "_"

Comment: select top 1 charindex('_',name) from sys.tables order by object_id desc
go
select top 1 left(name,(charindex('_',name))) from sys.tables order by object_id desc
go

Comment: @talapanenivinaychowdary and what happens if there is no underscore?